# How to navigate to edit page using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a table that contains different items. Each row has edit link. What I want is when the user clicks on the link, he will be taken to edit page with the ID of the item passed to the edit page. I want to do this either with ajax or jquery. How can I amend my code below so it will pass the ID to the edit page? I have the following ajax code, but it is not working:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edt").click(function() {
        var item= $(this).attr('rel'); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"edit_item.php",
                data:{
                    data:item,
                },

            });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<td><a id="edt" href="#" rel="<?php echo $ID;?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: That ajax code seems fine. Are you getting any error in browser's console?

Comment: I am not getting any error, the link is not clickable.

Comment: Link is clickable as I have shown in this fiddle and value of rel is also reaching JS code. Here is that fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/54hgz166/)

Comment: Have you added jQuery library before this JS code?

Comment: _"taken to edit page with the ID of the item passed to the edit page"_ -- this is what a link does, simply by being a link. No javascript or jquery needed, just a query parameter, something like: `<a href="edit_item.php?item=<?php echo $ID;?>">Edit</a>` -- and ajax is used to _avoid_ going to a new page, so no need for ajax.

Comment: _"Each row has edit link"_ -- if each row has that `<td><a id="edt" href=...>` then your first problem is that you are re-using the id of `edt`, every one of your links uses that id.  That is invalid, an `id` must be unique within a page. When you do `$("#edt").click(...)` to attach your handler, what happens is _undefined_, because there is only supposed to be _**one**_ "#edt" -- the handler may not attach to anything, or it could attach to just the first, or just the last #edt.  If you want a repeated thing, use a _**class**_ `<a class="edt" ...>` and a class selector `$(".edt").click(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Stephen. With your code I can now echo the ID of a given item. This IDs are dynamically generated. Each row has a unique ID. What I want now is how to pass this ID to edit_item.php page so as to use it to fetch the details of a given item from the database. If I can't use ajax, what else can I use here?

Comment: @Oponjous - as you say, each row has a unique php variable `ID` so each `rel="<?php echo $ID;?>"`is indeed unique, however each row has _the **same**_ `id="edt"` and that makes the HTML itself _invalid_ because an HTML `id="<something>"` must itself be unique within the page.  HTML that is _not valid_ leads to unpredictable behavior of CSS rules and, more importantly for you, _unpredictable javascript behavior_. It may be that your links don't do what you want because your click-handler was never attached to them, because you're trying to attach to `#edt` and there is illegally >1 `id="edt"`

Comment: @Stephen you are correct, but what should I do now?